# How do you send plaintext instead of HTML email from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'd like to send plain text emails from a Rails app. In my mail sending config I have:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = 'text/plain'
```

Nonetheless, when I send a test email from the Rails console, I get:

```
>> GeneralAppMailer.deliver_test

# ...

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And looking at it in Gmail, it does seem to be handled as HTML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Be sure your template ends with `.text.erb` extension and not `.html.erb`.
See [ActionMailer documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Comment: Thanks. Not `.txt.erb`, oops!

Comment: @Meekohi I made exactly the same mistake and was searching for some minutes to find out what was wring :D

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the `test` method in your `GeneralAppMailer` class, it's impossible to say, but  it's probably because you're rendering an HTML-based view template to send the message. But maybe you should post your code.